# How to limit users internet connection in a local internet?

Tags: vpn, windows-server-2003

We have LAN in our company. Right now internet is shared among the LAN through our Windows Server 2003. I want to have a VPN server on our server computer so users should connect to this VPN server if the want internet access. What is the best solution? Our goal is to monitor internet traffic usage.

Comment: uhm, VPN is used to connect to a private network from the internet... not the other way around. If you want to monitor internet traffic you could use a proxy server. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_server

Comment: Does ISA server do the thing that I want?

Comment: ISA Server used to be called MS Proxy, today it isn't even called ISA but Forefront.... ISA Server does web proxy, firewall and packet filtering... depends.  http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/isa/2000/enterprise/proddocs/en-us/isadocs/m_s_c_cometover.mspx?mfr=true